# Setup.exe and autorun.inf

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, project, autorun

I have Visual Studio 2008 project on which I added a Setup Project. It generates all files to install the application correctly.

Now I am trying to add an autorun.inf to the cd, which is supposed to start the Setup.exe.
After a lot of attempts and every combinations possible, nothing works, the install don't start. I even tried a batch file which start Setup.exe but no use.

Is there something I missing, because double-clicking on it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [autorun.inf page](http://autorun.moonvalley.com/) may help, especially the link about testing without burning a CD. Also check if [autorun is enabled](http://autorun.moonvalley.com/enable.htm) on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents...

- Did you begun you autorun.inf file with [autorun] ?
- Any trailing empty lines at the end of the autorun.inf file ?
- Are you sure autorun is activated on that CD drive ?
- Did you respect the syntax : open=filename.exe /param1
- Are your CD drive on the network (Windows will probably not allow a program to self execute on the intranet).

You have probably already checked all this twice. Best luck.